# SQL Query SSRS reports

Tags: sql, pivot

```
BUCKET1 BUCKET2 BUCKET3 BUCKET4 BUCKET5
-----------------------------------------------
NULL    NULL    10513261.05316  NULL    NULL
63609954.28567  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    7126516.29877   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11141469.82504
NULL    19493498.33978  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I have table like above. I want to select all the records but exclude NULL records like below.

```
BUCKET1          BUCKET2         BUCKET3       BUCKET4         BUCKET5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
63609954.28567   10513261.05316  7126516.29877 11141469.82504  19493498.33978
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Max/Min Aggregation like below:

```
select max(BUCKET1) as bucket1,max(BUCKET2) as bucket2,max(BUCKET3) as bucket3,max(BUCKET4) as bucket4,max(BUCKET5) as bucket5
from tablenmae
```